# Using ActionBar for android I want to add a menu button to the left of it

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I basically want to add a menu button to the far left of my action bar; like it does in the navigation drawer layout:

[image: Image of where exactly I want to add the menu icon]

There must be an easy way to do this, all of the tutorials I am reading seem far to complicated for something that is already available for a application template.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution: create a custom [`toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html)
Add a `imageview` and a `textview` to it.

```
 <toolbar ...>
    <imageview... /><--your image-->

 </toolbar>
```

Or you can change Activity icon.

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
```